# How to use a variable as object attribute in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a PaymentDetail model with attribute 'home_address_country', so i can use

```
    @payment_detail.home_address_country //where @payment_detail is object of that model.
```

I want to use something like this:---

```
country_attribute=address_type+"_address_country"  //where address type is equal to 'home'
 @payment_detail."#{country_attribute}"
```

**Means attribute name is stored in a variable. How can i do this?**

**EDIT**

```
country_attribute=address_type+"_address_country"
country_list=Carmen::country_names
eval("@#{country_attribute} = #{country_list}")
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

- **[Reading](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.3/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Read/read_attribute) AR attribute**

  ```
  @payment_detail.send("#{address_type}_address_country")
  ```

  *OR*

  ```
  @payment_detail.read_attribute("#{address_type}_address_country")
  ```
- **[Writing](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.3/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Write/write_attribute) AR attribute**

  ```
  @payment_detail.send("#{address_type}_address_country=", value)
  ```

  *OR*

  ```
  @payment_detail.write_attribute("#{address_type}_address_country", value)
  ```
- **[Setting](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_variable_set) instance variable**

  ```
  @payment_detail.instance_variable_set("@#{address_type}_address_country", value)
  ```
- **[Getting](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_variable_get) instance variable**

  ```
  @payment_detail.instance_variable_get("@#{address_type}_address_country")
  ```

**Reference**

- **send** method [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send)
- **read_attribute** method [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.3/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Read/read_attribute)
- **write_attribute** method [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.3/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Write/write_attribute)
- **instance_variable_get** method [documentation](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_variable_get)
- **instance_variable_set** method [documentation](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_variable_set)

Answer (score 4):

Recommended way for Rails 3 is to use [dictionary-like access](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/%5B%5D):

```
attr = @payment_detail["#{address_type}_address_country"]
attr = "new value"
@payment_detail["#{address_type}_address_country"] = attr
```

`read_attribute` and `write_attribute` methods work for Rails 2 only.

Comment: FYI, I'm testing this in Rails 4 and #read_attribute is still operational -- not sure about #write_attribute. I'm switching to use #send instead, though.