# Using variable to access object values like Javascripts object[var] in Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby

In JavaScript I could do this:

```
var someObject = {
    bar: "Hello, world"
};
foo="bar";
console.log (someObject[foo]);
```

And the console would show me "Hello world"

How do I do this in ruby?

```
#This does not work:
@someObject.bar="Hello, world" #@someObject holds a class
foo="bar"
puts @someObject[foo]
```

---

This is driving me nuts!

I have googled. Alot. None of the possible variations I could think of with "Ruby accessing object attributes with variable" and "Accessing a variable of an object using dynamic value in ruby" gave any results. What do you call this?

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913860/how-to-use-a-variable-as-object-attribute-in-rails).

Comment: If you just make that an answer, I'll mark it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby has more classical heritage, so objects are not extensible in the same way as in JavaScript. Depending on your use case, you would use a hash object or an open struct.

```
person = {
  "name": "John Smith"
}

puts person["name"]
```

Most of the time you'll see symbols be used instead of string literals.

```
person = {
  :name => "John Smith",
}

puts person[:name]
```

Finally you could use a struct or open struct if you really want to the same type of semantics as in JavaScript.

```
person = OpenStruct.new
person.name    = "John Smith"
person.age     = 70
person.pension = 300
```

Comment: Finally you could also do some meta programming, e.g method_missing resolves to an internal hash etc but seems like overkill for this case.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want [`Hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html).

```
someObject = {bar: "Hello, world!"}  # symbol
foo = :bar
someObject[foo]
# => "Hello, world!"
```

---

```
anotherObject = {"bar" => "Hello, another world!"}  # string
foo = "bar"
anotherObject[foo]
# => "Hello, another world!"
```