# Use json as properties\values for vagrantfile object

Tags: ruby, vagrant

Vagrantfile:

```
require 'json'

file = File.read('blueprint.json')
azure_data = JSON.parse(file)

Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  config.vm.define "master" do |node|
    node.vm.provider :azure do |azure, override|
      azure_data.each do |hash|
        hash.each do |key, value|
          azure[key] = value
        end
      end
      azure.vm_name = "somename"
    end
  end
end
```

`vagrant up` gives this error:

> Microsoft Azure Provider:
>   * The following settings shouldn't exist: []

Also, if I add `puts('something')` into the `hash.each` loop, it gets output not once per each property of JSON file, but 6 times (¿?) per each property

blueprint.json:

```
{
    "admin_username":"someuser",
    "location":"northeurope",
    "resource_group_name":"resourcegroup",
    "tcp_endpoints":"5000",
    "virtual_network_name":"vnetname",
    "vm_size":"Standard_DS1"
}
```

Comment: can you provide the `blueprint.json` file just to check

Comment: the Json reads the file, you dont provide which property you want to read - will make an answer as explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSon file is already a JSon object so when you'll read it, you directly have the key, value pair. You can do the following just to check

```
require 'json'

file = File.read('blueprint.json')
azure_data = JSON.parse(file)

azure_data.each do |key, value|
  p key
  p value
end
```

so when reading your JSon you can skip the `hash` part, ruby already knows this is a hash. 
Then you want to set the object properties dynamically, you need to use [send](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/send) method

```
require 'json'

file = File.read('blueprint.json')
azure_data = JSON.parse(file)

Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  config.vm.define "master" do |node|
    node.vm.provider :azure do |azure, override|
      azure_data.each do |key, value|
        azure.send("#{key}=", value)
      end
      azure.vm_name = "somename"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: well, that did simplify code a bit (thanks for that), but the error is still there (same error)

Comment: oops sorry . azure provider is not an array but an object, you can access properties with `.`

Comment: could you provide an example? `azure.key = value` gives `* The following settings shouldn't exist: key`

Comment: pff getting too tired, just add `if key.to_s.empty?` to avoid the error

Comment: oops, sorry, this doesn't really work :( it does nothing basically. i thought it worked, because the error went away, but it looks like it just picks up the defaults right now. none of the settings get applied

Comment: oh ok I tried, not sure why it didnt work, using send method instead, did a test and seems to work ok

Answer (score 0):

It appears that it is possible after all, courtesy of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913860/how-to-use-a-variable-as-object-attribute-in-rails).

```
config.vm.define "master" do |node_dotnet|
  node_dotnet.vm.provider :azure do |azure, override|
    azure_data.each do |key, value|
      azure.instance_variable_set("@#{key}", value)
    end 
    azure.vm_name = "master"
  end
end
```

Man, Ruby has a horrible syntax

ps. For some reason, not all of those methods work.

Comment: good I was looking at this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849521/set-attribute-dynamically-of-ruby-object and did test .. didnt see you have answered meanwhile, good you found

Comment: why does it need this weird syntax? I can't understand it at all. `send("#{key}=", value)` @FrédéricHenri

Comment: `#{key}` is ruby string interpolation and send method takes argument follow by = and the value as 2nd parameter

Comment: @FrédéricHenri but why does in this case it needs another syntax? `instance_variable_set("@#{key}", value)` so string interpolation is both `@#{}` and `#{}`?